# Some code that i don't understand of the ajax

Tags: ajax

The variable  `xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest()` is initialed. the following code :

```
function makerequest(serverPage,objID){
            var obj=document.getElementById(objID);
            xmlhttp.open("GET",serverPage);
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status ==200){
                    obj.innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.send(null);
        }
```

i am sorry i am a new learner of ajax, in the if condition, why it add `xmlhttp.readyState == 4`.  at the function's end there is using  `xmlhttp.send(null);` could i delete them. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you want to send the ajax request that you generate, so since you're using get, null is an acceptable argument. If you use post, you should pass the querystring in the send method. More [here](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp).

If you delete the readyState condition then you could end up with the ajax returning nothing since the page would not yet be ready. See more [here](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/xmldom/quickref/httpRequest_readyState.html).

EDIT: Sample argument for POST send method:

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","ajax_test.asp",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("fname=Henry&lname=Ford");
```

Comment: when i change the null param to another (arg) ,the code can't work why?

Comment: @user1345545 if you're sending a GET request with ajax, the send() method does not need an argument at all. You only need to put a parameter there when you're sending a POST request, and that parameter should be a query string (name value pairs) of the data you wish to post. See my edited post.